# for loop in Pandas to append values based on list condition

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, append

I am iterating through a dataframe of 2 columns, ["Tumor Volume (mm3)"] and ["Drug Regimen"]. I have a 2 lists made, one called Treatment with 4 specific drugs, and an empty list Tumor_Vol in which I want to append Tumor Volume based on the drug. If the row under the column ["Drug Regimen"] contains one of the drugs in the Treatment list, I want to append the ["Tumor Volume (mm3)"] value in that row to Tumor_Vol.

#my 2 lists
`your text`treatment = ["Capomulin", "Ramicane", "Infubinol", "Ceftamin"]`

```
`your text`Tumor_Vol = []
```

#to save time while looping I narrowed down my dataset to the 2 columns I need. This worked when I printed the dataset
`Tumor_Drug_df = merged_df[["Tumor Volume (mm3)", "Drug Regimen"]]

#looping through each row of the Drug column, checking to see if they match the drugs in the treatment list. If they do, append the Tumor Volume from that row into my Tumor_Vol list. Then print the list.
`your text`for row in Tumor_Drug_df["Drug Regimen"]:
`your text`if row == treatment:
`your text`Tumor_Vol.append(["Tumor Volume (mm3)"])
`your text`print(Tumor_Vol)

#this is my output: []... just a bunch of square brackets

All 4 drugs in the treatment list are present in my dataset. I know I'm not doing this correctly but I'm not sure how else to accomplish it

Comment: It would be much clearer if you provided reproducible code together with sample input(s) and expected results rather than a textual description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical solution according to your question is to loop over the dataframe and check whether the value is in the treatment list.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')
df = df[['Drug Regimen', 'Tumor Volume (mm3)']]
treatments = ['Capomulin', 'Ramicane', 'Infubinol', 'Ceftamin']

tumor_vol = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Drug Regimen'] in treatments:
        tumor_vol.append(row['Tumor Volume (mm3)'])

print(tumor_vol)
```

Note that if your dataset is very large, there are some faster options you can choose, since 'iterrows' is not the best way to work with dataframes.